# How to cancel the vote, if someone click on upvote/downvote button 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a upvote/downvote button [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/5/)
. Now i want it to cancel the vote, if someone click on the upvote/downvote button 2 times. Example: 1st click = vote +1/-1, 2nd click = vote -1/+1 (depending, if he click on upvote or downvote)

HTML:

```
<center><button class="buttonup" id="plus" style="vertical-align:middle" > <span>Upvote </span> </button>         <span id="count">0</span>
        <button  class="buttondw" id="minus" style="vertical-align:middle"><span>Downvote </span> </button></center>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function checkIfUserVoted() {
    return true ? localStorage.getItem("voted") === "true" : false
 }

var counter = 0;
if(localStorage.getItem("count") == null)
    $("#count").text(0);
else {
    counter = localStorage.getItem("count");
    $("#count").text(counter);
}


$("#plus").click(function(){

  if (checkIfUserVoted()) {

} else {
    localStorage.setItem("voted", "true");
    counter++;
  $("#count").text(counter);
  localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
  }

});

$("#minus").click(function(){

  if (checkIfUserVoted()) {

} else {
    localStorage.setItem("voted", "true");
    counter--;    
  $("#count").text(counter);
  localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: asked it in meta how SO did it :) I'm also interested cause SO done quite fast and optimal. I wonder how to design it

Comment: just put your logic in empty if statement you have for both click handlers.  

`if (checkIfUserVoted()) {

}`

Comment: Actually i am newbie Javascripter, one of my internet friend made it for me. But now, he is out of station for some months (no internet), please help me out.

Comment: Can u explain more properly what result u want when user click plus/minus second time? and why your data saved in localStorage?

Comment: Just like facebook like button. If someone clicks on the like button 1st time, he likes the post. If he clicks on it 2nd time, he unlikes it. That is what i want

Comment: so why u need two buttons?

Comment: If i design it I can put 2 buttons as you did. then I put 1 and -1 as data in button element. after clicking on it I replace this with -1 or 1. while actually updating votes I will use these data values. hope this help

Comment: If someone clicks on upvote, but then he thinks that, no i should not upvote it. So i want to give them a option to cancel the vote without clicking on downvote.

Comment: guru, i did not got you :(

Comment: can someone make the script for me?

Comment: you need to try edit it youtself, for your logic you need to save last button that user click and check is this same button he click now, if it is - inc/dec count. all of this you need do in the if statement that i posted before. just try to do something, and post link to result

Comment: Hi @tehkc check my given answer, it is working as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this only saving one data to localstorage current number of votes. Try running this code..

```
var counter = 0, // Try change this what ever you want
  votePlus = counter + 1,
  voteMinus = counter - 1;

function checkIfUserVoted() {
  return localStorage.getItem("voted");
}
if (!localStorage.getItem("voted")) {
  localStorage.setItem("voted", counter);
  $("#count").text(counter);
}
$("#plus").click(function() {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != votePlus ? votePlus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $("#count").text(vote);
});
$("#minus").on('click', function() {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != voteMinus ? voteMinus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $("#count").text(vote);
});
```

See this [working fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/10/)

Answer (score 1):

I added downvote function to check if user has downvoted, and made some other changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkIfUserVoted() {
    return true ? localStorage.getItem("voted") === "true" : false
}
function checkIfUserdownVoted() {
    return true ? localStorage.getItem("downvoted") === "true" : false
}

var counter = 0;
if(localStorage.getItem("count") == null)
    $("#count").text(0);
else {
    counter = localStorage.getItem("count");
    $("#count").text(counter);
}


$("#plus").click(function(){

  if (checkIfUserVoted()) {
  localStorage.setItem("downvoted", "false");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("voted", "true");
    localStorage.setItem("downvoted", "false");
    counter++;
  $("#count").text(counter);
  localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
  }

});

$("#minus").click(function(){

  if (checkIfUserdownVoted()) {
  localStorage.setItem("voted", "false");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("downvoted", "true");
    localStorage.setItem("voted", "false");
    counter--;    
  $("#count").text(counter);
  localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but can u make it so that user can cancel his vote by clicking on upvote button again instead of clicking on downvote button? Also allow them to downvote, if they upvote once. (CUrrently user can just cancel the upvote, by clicking on downvote button)

Answer (score 0):

This one will work without setting counter variable beforehand

[JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/15/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkIfUserUpVoted() {
        return true ? localStorage.getItem("upvoted") === "true" : false
    }

    function checkIfUserDownVoted() {
        return true ? localStorage.getItem("downvoted") === "true" : false
    }

    var counter = 0;
    if (localStorage.getItem("count") == null)
        $("#count").text(0);
    else {
        counter = localStorage.getItem("count");
        $("#count").text(counter);
    }


    $("#plus").click(function() {
        if (checkIfUserUpVoted()) {
            counter = parseInt(counter) - 1;
            localStorage.setItem("upvoted", "false");
        } else if (checkIfUserDownVoted()) {
            counter = parseInt(counter) + 2;
            localStorage.setItem("downvoted", "false");
            localStorage.setItem("upvoted", "true");
        } else if (!checkIfUserVoted()) {
            counter = parseInt(counter) + 1;
            localStorage.setItem("upvoted", "true");
        }
        $("#count").text(parseInt(counter));
        localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
        updateValues();
    });

    $("#minus").click(function() {
        if (checkIfUserUpVoted()) {
            counter = parseInt(counter) - 2;
            localStorage.setItem("upvoted", "false");
            localStorage.setItem("downvoted", "true");
        } else if (checkIfUserDownVoted()) {
            counter = parseInt(counter) + 1;
            localStorage.setItem("downvoted", "false");
        } else if (!checkIfUserVoted()) {
            counter = parseInt(counter) - 1;
            localStorage.setItem("downvoted", "true");
        }
        $("#count").text(parseInt(counter));
        localStorage.setItem("count", counter);
        updateValues();
    });
});
```